# Linear regression with non-linear terms

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

It is a general question on linear regression with polynomial terms. I am using `x` and `x^2` as my independent variables and my regression equation is as follows `y=a0+a1*x+a2*x^2+a3*z+e`. I am doing regression to find the coefficients. I have read through [this](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/curves.htm) article, which explains that I need to de-mean the variable x before I run the regression to obtain my coefficients `a1` and `a2`. Once we de-mean our new variables (de-meaned and its square) are not correlated.

I was wondering is it necessary to always de-mean the variables when we use the polynomial term as well?

EDIT: Clarifying further - when i am using the linear and quadratic terms both. Do I need to de-mean the linear term (call it demean_x) and take the square of it (demean-x^2) and use them for regression instead of x and x^2.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? I don't understand your question as stated. What role is "as well" playing in the question?

Comment: @gung what I meant is - when i am using the linear and quadratic terms both. Do I need to de-mean the linear term (call it demean_x) and take the square of it (demean-x^2) and use them for regression instead of x and x^2. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: It's not always *necessary* to to do it for the quadratic, but it's a good idea to do it.

Comment: I don't think the article you linked to actually says you "_need_ to de-mean the variable x before [you] run the regression."  It only says that demeaning can make the coefficients easier to interpret.

Comment: @Adrian, you are right..

Comment: @Glen_b - If I demean will the statistical significance will change? thanks

Comment: The significance of what in particular?

Comment: @Glen_b statistical significance of the coefficients obtained.

Comment: It sounds like you should edit your question